# Bash script to change file names recursively

Tags: bash, shell

I have a script for changing file names of mht files but it does not traverse through dirs and sub dirs. I asked a question on a local forum and I got an answer that this is a solution:

```
find . -type f -name "*.mhtml" -o  -type f -name "*.mht" | xargs -I item sh -c '{ echo item; echo item | sed "s/[:?|]//g"; }' | xargs -n2 mv
```

But it generates an error. With some of my experimenting it turns out that `sh -c` breaks file names with space and that this generates an error. How can I fix this?

```
#!/bin/bash
# renames.sh
# basic file renamer
for i in  . *.mht
do
j=`echo $i | sed 's/|/ /g' | sed 's/:/ /g' | sed 's/?//g' | sed 's/"//g'`
    mv "$i" "$j"
    done
```

Comment: What if you tried this: `find . -type f \( -name "*.mhtml" -o -name "*.mht" \) | xargs -I item sh -c '{ echo \"item\"; echo \"item\" | sed "s/[:?|]//g"; }' | xargs -n2 mv`

Comment: it generates similar error

Answer (score 2):

```
#! /bin/bash
find . -type f \( -name "*.mhtml" -o -name ".mht" \) -print0 |
while IFS= read -r -d '' source; do
    target="${source//[:?|]/}"
    [ "X$source" != "X$target" ] &&
    mv -nv "$source" "$target"
done
```

**Update:** Do the rename according to the original question, and added support for `.mht`.

Comment: It also doesn't handle .mht files

Answer (score 1):

Use `rename`. With rename you can specify a renaming pattern:

```
find . -type f \( -name "*.mhtml" -o -name "*.mht" \) -print0 | xargs -0 -I'{}' rename  's/[:?|]//g' "{}"
```

This way you can properly handle names with spaces. xargs will replace {} with every names of file provided by the find command. Also note the use of -print0 and -0. This use a \0 as a separator so its avoid problems dealing with filnames containing \n (newline).

The -o was not working the way it was intended to. you must use parenthesis to group conditions.

You may also consider using -iname instead of -name if you deal with file ending with ".mHtml".

Comment: @user The secret is to test before posting! You know you can accept my answer if it solve your problem. Accepting an answer help the community, otherwise people spend time on your question to realise that there is already a valid solution.